# Set variables dynamically by passing parameters by reference in a Groovy closure

Tags: java, groovy, reference, closures

Is there a way I can set a variable by calling a closure in groovy?
VAR1 returns 2 but I would expect it to return the value in cell I2.

```
def f_getdata = {ColDesc, ColNum -> 
ColDesc = Float.parseFloat(sheet.getRow(1).getCell(ColNum).getRawValue())}

def VAR1 = 2

f_getdata(VAR1, 8)
```

Comment: arguments are passed by value, not by reference.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is impossible in Groovy or there's a workaround?

Comment: I'm not a Groovy expert, but why don't you simply use a method, and return from that method: `def var1 = getData(8);`?

Comment: The real closure is more complex than what I posted: `def f_noNullfld_Getdata_TaxCheck = {ColDesc, ColNum, TaxCompare ->
 if (f_isNULL(ColNum)) {MarkError(j,err1)}
 else
 {ColDesc = Float.parseFloat(myrow.getCell(ColNum).getRawValue())
 if (ColDesc > TaxCompare) {MarkError(ColNum,err2)}}}`     I just don't want to repeat the same block of code for each column in the excel file. I assumed closures would help with that. It  just doesn't seem to like that I'm trying to set a variable in it..

Answer (score 1):

The most of simple-like types (String, Integer, Long, ...) are non-changeable.

So you can't do what you've described.

But if `VAL1` will be in a container -  for example `Map` - then you can change values in the Map:

```
def ctx = [
    VAL1:"world"
]
def f_getdata = {ColDesc, ColNum -> 
    ctx[ColDesc] = "hello "+ ctx[ColDesc]
}
f_getdata("VAL1", 8)

println ctx.VAL1
```

result:

```
hello world
```